# Truly borderless <select> dropdown in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems making `<select>` HTML elements 100% borderless in HTML. I get close by using this:

```
.cfmobileform select {
    border:0px;
    outline:0px;
    background-color:white;
    background:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
}
```

But there is still a hint of a top border in Chrome & Safari.

[image: <select> still has border]

I have extensively searched Google but can find nothing. Is this possible?

Comment: Try adding this rule: `border-color: transparent;`

Comment: I don't see anything here: https://jsfiddle.net/5e80j33L/

Comment: thx. Turns out there was a rogue box-shadow being applied by Bootstrap. I removed it using box-shadow: none;.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a rogue box-shadow being applied by Bootstrap. I removed it using box-shadow: none;